# How do I repair a broken Skype group chat (window)?

Tags: skype

I am using Ubuntu 11.10 and Skype 2.2.0.35. Everything was working just fine and then suddenly one of the group chat windows, to a group chat I always use, goes missing. I of course go to reopen it by double clicking the entry in the history list, but that does nothing. I try the same thing on another group chat's entry/row in the history list and that group chat's window comes right up.

I look around my workspaces for a while, trying to get to it. I try clicking on an event notification (window) when someone in the group chat types something (because this normally brings up the group chat window) and nothing. I try tinkering with the settings. I try closing Skype and opening it again. I try uninstalling and reinstalling Skype. I try uninstalling, rebooting and then reinstalling again.

Perplexed, I decide to install CompizConfig Settings Manager after reading it allows the user to move windows. (My thinking was that the group chat window might be opening up in some unreachable space and I can move it to the center of my screen with the CompizConfig key combo.) I try it to no avail, although it works great with all windows I can see.

At this point I am starting to really accept that something is seriously wrong with some information that Skype is storing for the group chat and that the window just does not launch.

My next idea to fix this is to reset all local Skype settings, but I am not sure how. Is there a hidden folder in my home directory or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay I figured it out.

Skype stores user settings in ~/.Skype, so what I did was uninstall Skype, then in a shell, in my home directory:

```
mv .Skype skype_backup
```

I then reinstalled Skype and my "broken" group chat window now comes up!

I will probably just delete that skype_backup, but I will keep it around for a little while to be safe.